# If condition in @{} inside <dd> in ASP.NET MVC Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am doing a simple thing to render an image in ASP.NET MVC View.  I need to use c# if condition. I am using that as below :

```
  <dd>
       @{ byte[] photo = @Model.Photo;
          string imageSrc = null;
          if (photo != null) { }

             //Logic

       }

        <img src="" alt="Image" />       

    </dd>
```

I am getting exception { is required. any help ? I am sure I do not need any braces

Comment: Remove @ from @Model.Photo;, it should work.

Comment: No it won't . I tried

Answer (score 2):

From [there](http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/embedding-images-in-html-using-c/http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/embedding-images-in-html-using-c/):

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Photo, Base64FormattingOptions.None)"
    alt="Image" />
```

Note converting byte array into base64 string (`Convert.ToBase64String`), which gives you exactly what you want.

Comment: This is a good answer. But I am not doing the inline conversion because I need to subtract 78 from photo length. Photo is from Microsoft Northwind database and it is an OLE object. Any way we can start from 78 not 0 in the inline conversion ?

Comment: and when I tried below passing offset value, it is throwing invalid arguments 
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Photo, 78 ,Base64FormattingOptions.None)"
                 alt="Image" />

Answer (score 0):

Okay this worked

```
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Photo,78,Model.Photo.Length-78 ,Base64FormattingOptions.None)"
             alt="Image" />
```

Comment: You might want to mark my answer as accepted then. Also, I suggest do not do anything with your viewmodel in a view and do that in a controller.

Comment: Yes that is the next. I will refactor this

Comment: sometimes converting `base64` as shown in this answer creates problem in IE ... just check it...

Comment: @Kartikeya there are always problems with IE. That's why there are alternatives (including new IE). And the people who do not want to use an alternative, never can say why.

Comment: @AgentFire...this answer even creates problems with newer versions of IE also...and in my opinion we should keep in mind all the browsers because after all IE is also a browser and a chunk of people use IE even today...

Answer (score 0):

@Debug_mode, I tried this by creating a sample mvc app, it works for me.

```
<dd>
   @{ 
      byte[] photo = Model.Photo;
      string imageSrc = null;
      if (photo != null) { }
         //Logic
   }

    <img src="" alt="Image" />       

</dd>
```

Note: if we are using C# block @{..} we dont want to use '@' for accessing Sever properties inside the @{....} c# block i.e it should be simply Model.Photo instead @Model.Photo.